# What is the best way to create a library from existing functions?

Tags: library, array

I was tasked to take functions that work, and create a library with these functions.

Take a look at the following function that existed inside a program:

```
char* Num_to_HEX_char_array(int32_t value)
{
  Clear_array(MyTempArray, MY_TEMP_ARRAY_LENGTH);
  ltoa(value, MyTempArray, HEX);
  return MyTempArray;
}
```

(Let's ignore the fact that this function)
This cannot be immediately made into a library, as `MyTempArray` is non existant.
This, in the `.cpp` file, i will have to manually create these lines:

```
#define MY_TEMP_ARRAY_LENGTH 20
char MyTempArray[MY_TEMP_ARRAY_LENGTH];
```

Now the library compiles fine.
However, this library can be called by many programs that I create, and some of them might require a different array length, while others ay require a different name than this one.

So what is the best way to create this library?

*One approach that I thought was to dynamically create these arrays with `malloc()`.
And then, on the main program, you will have to `realloc()` the arrays with the ones you want.
Also, use `undef` and re`#define`.
The drawbacks to this approach is that you have to remember to ALWAYS use these statements, if you want your library to work

*Another approach is to place all this code:

```
#define MY_TEMP_ARRAY_LENGTH 20
char MyTempArray[MY_TEMP_ARRAY_LENGTH];
```

inside a configuration header file. The variables will be of global scope.
Then, when you create an application, you will only have to change this file.

My question to this approach is How exactly can you make sure that this configuration file is read by all the libraries?

Maybe you many libraries, for example, string-handling, or sensor-handling...
Each and every one of these user-created libraries have to `#include` and see that configuration header file, in order to make sure that the definitions and arrays of correct/name and size.
How can you do this so that it is visible by all your user-created libraries?
Where is the optimal location to place that file?

In general, what is the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: what do you mean when you say `best`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd write such a function to expect the calling function to allocate the array and pass it and its size as arguments. That leaves the memory allocation and deallocation up to each library user, who may want/need (for other reasons) to use a static array, heap memory, or an automatic array and allows them to de-allocate it (or not) when their application no longer needs it. Coding these details into your library would restrict its usability.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I must say I have an issue with the example you provide.
The function `Num_to_HEX_char_array()` should use an array that has the
maximum size that `ltoa()` may ever need. No more, no less. There is no
point in letting the user of the library choose this size. Here is how I
would implement this function:

```cpp
char *Num_to_HEX_char_array(int32_t value)
{
    static char buffer[2 * sizeof(long) + 1];
    return ltoa(value, buffer, HEX);
}
```

That being said, I am willing to accept the idea that your library has
some static buffers for which it does make sense to let the user choose
the size. You could probably find a better example to put in the
question though.

In this case, I would suggest you first consider the approach proposed
by JRobert, and let the user provide those buffers. Using static buffers
in a library can make the API easier to use in the most common cases.
There are many function in the C standard library that do this, like,
e.g. [`ctime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3p.html). This, however, comes at a cost:

- the user must be well aware that calls to the library can clobber
  data returned by previous calls
- the functions are not re-entrant, meaning they cannot be used in
  multiple threads, and they cannot be used both in interrupt and
  non-interrupt contexts.

This is why you have functions such as [`ctime_r()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3p.html): to provide an
alternative that lets the user handle the buffer, and does not suffer
from the previous shortcomings.

If you still believe you want static buffers inside your library, then
you should first consider whether it is possible to fix the size, like
in the `Num_to_HEX_char_array()` example. If this is not possible, then
the best I can think of is to use C++ templates. For example:

```cpp
template<size_t size> class CircularBuffer {
    int buffer[size];
    // ...
};
```

which would be instantiated like this:

```cpp
// Let `queue' be a 42-slot circular buffer.
CircularBuffer<42> queue;
```

Keep in mind, though, that this technique forces you to put most of the
code in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

Command line compilers and most IDEs for C and C++ enable to set project defines as -D parameters in project settings. Arduino IDE does not enable this yet, because it doesn't have a project configuration file.

With Arduino IDE you can add defines for platform or for board definitions with build.extra_flags in platform.local.txt or in boards.local.txt. Example for boards.local.txt for Arduino Mega:

`mega.build.extra_flags=-DUIP_CONF_UDP_CONNS=20 -DUIP_CONF_MAX_LISTENPORTS=30`

platform.local.txt and boards.local.txt must be in boards package folder nect to platform.txt and boards.txt.